# Installing C library in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, geoip

I'm trying to use [GeoIP](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) with Django. It requires the [MaxMind GeoIP C API](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/c/).

If I were using Ruby, I could simply use the 'geoip' gem which bundles the C API and the Ruby bindings, as explained in [Installing MaxMind GeoIP ruby library on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368461/installing-maxmind-geoip-ruby-library-on-heroku).

Unfortunately, nothing like this exists for Python, so I'm wondering how I would go about installing the C API from source on Heroku, or if there's the equivalent of a package manager on Heroku (ie. 'brew install geoip' for OS X, and 'sudo apt-get install geoip' for Ubuntu).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-geoip/ ?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to write your own buildpack to compile anything in Heroku, at the time you push code and in your requirements.txt there's a package with a binary requirement. See the python buildpack code to guide your work https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python