# How to install PyEnchant on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, spell-checking, pyenchant

It seems that PyEnchant requires the C enchant library. How would I go about installing this on Heroku, is that possible?

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668936/installing-c-library-in-heroku), I would need to write my own build pack for Heroku, so I guess that's one way. But I'm hoping there is a simpler technique to use?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: I didn't. Ended up using NLTK to build my own solution.

Comment: Yeah me too. Wrote my own spellchecker. Heroku support responded but writing a build pack for this wasn't worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of things we are using [`heroku-buildpack-apt`](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt), which let's you install any package.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the answer of [Denis Cornehl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194456/denis-cornehl) I add an `Aptfile` to the project with this content:

```
libenchant-dev
```

And that removed the error of the C library.

However in my case I can't find a way of add a spanish dictionary, I tried add `myspell-es` in the same Aptfile, but without success.

**UPDATE:** Since I was having problems with the spanish dictionary. I stopped trying to deploy that way and I use a Dockerfile. This way I have more control of which OS libraries install. With this Dockerfile I was able to use pyenchant with a spanish dictionary (By the way, my app uses Flask, for that the CMD command uses gunicorn):

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install libenchant-dev hunspell hunspell-es

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY app.py .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app
```

And the way to deploy it is slightly different:

```
heroku login
heroku create <your_app_name>
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web --app <your_app_name>
heroku container:release web --app <your_app_name>
```

I hope this helps you.